# Add new Data Row in Google Visualisation

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I am trying to making dynamic Google Line chart. I am fetching my datatable from Google Sheet.
I added `eventlistener` in html to update the data row. So that, existing data row gets updated.
My aim is to delete existing data rows from the chart and new data rows.

Code.gs:

```js
function getTableDataTV(){
  //Chart load with this datatable
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById("").getSheetByName("Sheet 1"); //2nd worksheet ID
  const data = ws.getRange (2,1,ws.getLastRow() -1, 9).getDisplayValues();
 
return data

}

function getvoddata() {
//new data table for eventlistener
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("");//2nd worksheet ID
  const sw = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 2");
  var finaldata = sw.getRange (2,1,sw.getLastRow() -1, 9).getDisplayValues();
  return finaldata
}
```

HTML:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getData);
      var chart;
      var options;

function getData(){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawChart).getTableDataTV();
}
          function drawChart(dataReturned) {

      data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date', 'Days');
      data.addColumn('number', 'A');
      data.addColumn('number', 'B');
      data.addColumn('number', 'C');
      data.addColumn('number', 'D');
      var newData =  dataReturned.map(r => [new Date(r[0].slice(6,10),r[0].slice(0,2),r[0].slice(3,5)), parseInt(r[1]),parseInt(r[2]),parseInt(r[3]),parseInt(r[4])]);

      data.addRows(newData);
       options = {
             
          title: 'Total Views',
          subtitle: 'ABP News Vs Competitor Channels'
           
            };
       chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart'));

      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
    }

//Update Data Row

document.getElementById("pd1").addEventListener("click",newchart);
function newchart(){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateChart).getvoddata();
}
    function updateChart(newdataReturned) {
       
                   
 data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date', 'Days');
      data.addColumn('number', 'A');
      data.addColumn('number', 'B');
      data.addColumn('number', 'C');
      data.addColumn('number', 'D');
      var newData =  newdataReturned.map(r => [new Date(r[0].slice(6,10),r[0].slice(0,2),r[0].slice(3,5)), parseInt(r[1]),parseInt(r[2]),parseInt(r[3]),parseInt(r[4])]);

      data.addRows(newData);           

          // redraw the chart.
          chart.draw(data, options);        
      
      }
        
    </script>
.....
<body>...
<a id="pd1">VOD</a>
<div id="chart" style="width: 1000px; height: 400px"></div>
</body>
```

I am also getting error on console when add below line:

```js
document.getElementById("pd1").addEventListener("click",newchart);
```

Error:
`Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`

I got this `updatefunction` from this [website](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/333532) and it is working on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/R6Sh8/).
Please check, what I am doing wrong here.

**Thank You**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your HTML and Javascript are modified. I thought that when I saw your HTML and Javascript, the button is not shown in your HTML, and also, the container for inserting the chart is not shown. And, when I modified your HTML and Javascript by these situations and your sample script shown in your jsfiddle.

```html
<div id="chart"></div>
<button id="pd1">update chart</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(getData);
var chart;
var data;
var options;

document.getElementById("pd1").addEventListener("click", newchart);

function getData() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawChart).getTableDataTV();
}

function newchart() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateChart).getvoddata();
}

function drawChart(dataReturned) {
  data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Days');
  data.addColumn('number', 'A');
  data.addColumn('number', 'B');
  data.addColumn('number', 'C');
  data.addColumn('number', 'D');
  var newData = dataReturned.map(r => [new Date(r[0].slice(6, 10), r[0].slice(0, 2), r[0].slice(3, 5)), parseInt(r[1]), parseInt(r[2]), parseInt(r[3]), parseInt(r[4])]);
  data.addRows(newData);
  options = { title: 'Total Views', subtitle: 'ABP News Vs Competitor Channels' };
  chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

function updateChart(newdataReturned) {
  data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Days');
  data.addColumn('number', 'A');
  data.addColumn('number', 'B');
  data.addColumn('number', 'C');
  data.addColumn('number', 'D');
  var newData = newdataReturned.map(r => [new Date(r[0].slice(6, 10), r[0].slice(0, 2), r[0].slice(3, 5)), parseInt(r[1]), parseInt(r[2]), parseInt(r[3]), parseInt(r[4])]);

  data.addRows(newData);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

#### Note:

- **In this modification, it supposes that your functions `getTableDataTV()` and `getvoddata()` at Google Apps Script return the correct values you expect. Please be careful this.**

Comment: Hi, Yes both function return correct values and modified my script similar to the website. But mine is Line chart.

Comment: and the code on jsfiddle is from the website itself

Comment: @Gaurav K.M. Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue from `But mine is Line chart.` and `and the code on jsfiddle is from the website itself `. Can I ask you about the detail of it?